# Is it possible to secure a JSON API from CSRF attacks without a same origin policy?

Tags: csrf

Is same origin necessary to prevent CSRF (I know it is not sufficient)?
Or can it be done without any same origin policies? This is for a client rendered app where I can't hide the token in an element on the page.

Comment: I think more detail on the problem is needed. Does "client rendered" here mean e.g. an Electron (or other locally-hosted) app or broadly "a website where the HTML is rendered by JavaScript", and where is the potential source of attack? It's not obvious to me what about the setup you figure makes tokens unworkable or takes the same-origin policy out of the picture.

Comment: A website where the HTML is rendered by Javascript. It may not be the same domain that is calling the JSON endpoint to get the data to render.

Comment: Hm, I might be misinterpreting you, but some API requests generally aren't vulnerable to CSRF or cross-site leakage: has to be a GET without side effects, without CORS enabled, and not a response type that can be used from other domains (so, JSON not JSONP). You can use a request like that to initially get a token to the client, then pass the token with the later side-effectful requests where you *do* have to worry about CORS.

Comment: Last word of the previous comment should be "CSRF" not "CORS". (And sorry if I guessed incorrectly about the problem!)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a typical example of a CSRF attack:

1. You log into a banking site, and now you have a session cookie keeping you logged in.
2. You visit a malicious site which sends a POST request to `/transfer_funds`.
3. The cookies are sent along with the POST request.
4. The request is authenticated and now your money is now sent to the attacker.

Now, let's look at every step and see how they can be prevented.

Step 1 can be prevented by not having login cookies, but that's incredibly inconvenient and impractical.

Step 2 can be prevented by being really careful about what sites you visit, but that's also incredibly inconvenient and you can't guarantee your users do that. You might think that a CORS policy could help, but it doesn't, as there are multiple ways to bypass it. The `fetch` api has a `no-cors` mode that ignores the CORS header and just doesn't make the response available, but in this case the attacker doesn't care about the response, only the request. Also, another common thing is to fill out a form using javascript then submit the form using javascript, also bypassing CORS.

Step 3 can be bypassed using the [`SameSite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) attribute of cookies, specifically `Lax` or `Strict`. For `Lax`, cookies are only sent on third party requests if it's a GET request, and your site should be designed so that no GET requests can do anything bad. For `Strict`, third party sites can't send cookies at all, which means they can't even exploit GET requests. This is probably the best solution, and most browsers use `SameSite=Lax` by default, which means CSRF is not a major issue. **If you want to be sure that your users are safe, you can set `SameSite=Lax` or `SameSite=Strict` explicitly on your cookies.**

Step 4 can be prevented with the classic CSRF token+CORS, which requires an attacker to make a GET request to get the CSRF token before they can make the POST request. However, since they actually need the response now, `no-cors` won't work and they can't authenticate as you.

Also, as a side note, if you have no cookies at all, then CSRF isn't an issue.

Comment: I see. So it seems like I either need to depend on SameSite or no-cors if I want to support , which means that my client facing webpage needs to be hosted on the same domain as the backend web service. Could checking the Referer value in the header on the backend provide a way to give the CSRF token to a whitelisted domains only?

Comment: **If** you implement a CSRF token then you're good to go. `no-cors` allows requests to go through but they **cannot** see the response. Which means, your CSRF token is safe and only your user will have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but there's overhead.

Issue a token on a successful login. Because you aren't passing it back and forth on the page it will be necessary to use some back end storage (e.g. session state) on the server to associate it with the logged in user's session. This is the overhead.

Now, every call to the API that can change state must include the token e.g. in the header. The token may be cached on the client. No token, no access for anything that changes state.

Congrats, you have defeated CSRF attacks. You'll still have to handle all the usual admin aspects e.g. token expiration, token renewal, etc.

Comment: for client side storage, how do I prevent a malicious site from using the stored token?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage